# How to solve a problem about two c++ header file that refers to each other?

Tags: c++, c++11, header-files

c++ header file "a.h" :

```
#pragma once
#include "b.h"

struct A {
    void f() {
        b.f();
    }
    B b;
    int i;
};
```

c++ header file "b.h" :

```
#pragma once
#include"a.h"

struct B {
    void f() {
        int x = a->i; //error occur
    }
    A* a;
};
```

"test.cpp":

```
#include "a.h"

int main(){
    A a;
    a.f();
}
```

Call 'a->i' in B will trigger error.Why?How to solve it.

Comment: you may use in header #ifndef _HEADER_NAME_H_ #define _HEADER_NAME_H_ {.. any code with inclusions here} #endif

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with the include paradigm that C++ inherited from C. You cannot solve this.

What you have to do is remove the line `#include "a.h"` in file b.h and forward declare `struct A;` before using it in `B`.

`b.h`

```
#pragma once

struct A;
struct B {
    void f();
    A* a;
};
```

`b.cpp`

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

void B::f() {
    int x = a->i;
}
```

Otherwise you have circular inclusion.

Comment: Also move the definition of `B::f` to `b.cpp` right?

Comment: Yes, I already added this.